# Getting error when update the Spring-boot version in pom.xml?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, log4j, parent-pom

I update the spring-boot parent version from 1.2.5 to 1.5.9.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

After update the version, below error message is appear for `spring-boot-starter-log4j`.

```
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar is missing.
```

Here is the `spring-boot-starter-log4j` dependancy in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: maybe you can try spring-boot-starter-log4j2 for solve problem

Answer (score 4):

Try using log4j2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For going back to log4j i.e log4j 1 you will have to do some customization.

Comment: Thanks @kakabali. When I update into log4j2 and run the project below errors are appeared.   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/path_to_m2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/path_to_m2/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.7/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Comment: your 2 dependencies

**`slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar`** 
**`log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar`**

are clashing

Comment: please share all dependencies

Comment: refer this - https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings it says for exclusions you need to do

Comment: Thnx @kakabali. How can I stop the clashing of that two jars.

Comment: using exclusions for your dependencies, explore a little bit, you have to check which dependency you need to have exclusions

Comment: something like this



`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>`

Comment: reference url - http://www.springboottutorial.com/logging-with-spring-boot-logback-slf4j-and-log4j

Comment: Thanks @kakabali. Below I share the dependencies that I used in my project.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: quite a lot of dependencies, can you check in dependencies hierarchy if where is slf4j-log4j12

Comment: can you run mvn dependency:tree on your code's root and check slf4j implementations, and accordingly you can make exclusions

Comment: I guess you can accept this as answer, as your initial problem seems to be resolved, not it is a different issue?